# "No module named '_sqlite3'" when running Django's "python3 manage.py migrate"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to learn Django and I installed it in my virtual environment and named it `myenv`, and I started a project named `mysite`. 
When I tried to run the `manage.py` file, it kept saying sqlite3 is not installed. I did install it, but it is saying the same error. When I run `python3 manage.py migrate`, it says:

```
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'"
```

I installed sqlite using the commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/backports
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
```

Comment: When you run command **sqlite3** in terminal, do you get the `sqlite>` prompt

Comment: yeah,  i get that

Comment: but doesnot work

Comment: install sqlite3 using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/backports` and
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install sqlite3`

Comment: Which Django version are you using? I had the same problem. Then I downgraded Django and things worked again.

Comment: im currently using version 2.0.6

Comment: okay i willl try that out

Comment: which version did you downgraded to

Answer (score 3):

I saw the same error too with Python `3.7` in Ubuntu Xenial `16.04` and the following fixed it for me:

Install libsqlite3:

```
sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev
```

Reinstall Python 3.7:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3.tgz
tar -xvf Python-3.7.3.tgz 
cd Python-3.7.3/
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 1):

This relates to [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993890/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sqlite3)

The problem might be that your Python installation does not include sqlite3, which is usually in the standard lib.

You should try installing libsqlite3-dev (`sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev`), then reinstalling Python.

Comment: do i have to uninstall the python to run that command or i can do with it

Comment: You can run the command without uninstalling Python, but it will not solve your issue.

Comment: @NikeshThapa What version of Python are you using? And how did you install it? (Some repo? Compiled it?)

Comment: sudo apt install python3

Answer (score 0):

I'm using python 3.6 and django version `1.11.3` I got the same error it was fixed doing these steps:

1. Install `pysqlite3`:

   `pip install pysqlite3`
2. change `base.py` line 33 to:

```py
from pysqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
```

The `base.py` file is located under "lib" directory of your virtualenv: `path_to_virtualenv/lib/python_interpreter_name/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py`

In my case: `path_to_my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py`

Update:
If you encountered the same problem in newer django versions (such as "2.0.7") you should change line 8 of `base.py`.(tested with django version "2.0.7")